# Using Velocity combined with Java, I'm trying to pull a single field from a '.' delimited string

Tags: java, velocity

I have my velocity directive set as #set ($stringList = $string.split("."))

I have tried the following in my syntax but can't get it to work

```
$stringList.get(0)
$stringList[0]
$stringList.[0]
${stringList}.get(0)
```

Comment: try changing to `$string.split("\\.")`

Answer (score 1):

change

```
#set ($stringList = $string.split("."))
```

to

```
#set ($stringList = $string.split("\\."))
```

and access it like

```
$stringList[0]
```